# ClipsSwapAreaElement Method must have a return type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey I´ve tried to solve this problem that was given to me by the author of the model althought I don´t know anything about unity coding. Could you help me handle this? Says ClipsSwapAreaElement Method must have a return type and dunno if there´s something on ClipSwapItem.

public class ClipSwapAreaElement : VisualElement
{
public Action OnClose { get; set; }

```
    private List<ClipSwapAreaElement> _animationsToSwap;


    public ClipSwapItem (VrcAnimationLayer layer)
    {
        new Label("Animations Swap Mode")
            .WithClass("header")
            .ChildOf(this);
        
        new Label("Do NOT modify the animator while you're swapping animations with the manager to avoid issues.")
            .WithClass("warning-label", "bordered-container")
            .WithFontSize(10)
            .ChildOf(this);

        _animationsToSwap = new List<ClipSwapItem>();
        
        if (layer.Controller != null)
        {
            foreach (var animatorLayer in layer.Controller.layers)
            {
                var clips = animatorLayer.GetClipsToSwap().ToList();
                
                _animationsToSwap.AddRange(clips);

                var container = new VisualElement()
                    .WithClass("bordered-container") 
                    .ChildOf(this);

                new Label(animatorLayer.name)
                    .WithClass("header-small")
                    .ChildOf(container);
                
                var clipsContainer = new VisualElement()
                    .WithClass("clips-container")
                    .ChildOf(container);
                foreach (ClipSwapItem clip in clips)
                {
                    if (clip.IsTree)
                    {
                        void MakeTree(ClipSwapItem clipSwapItem, VisualElement parentObject)
                        {
                            var foldout = new Foldout().ChildOf(parentObject);
                            foldout.text = clipSwapItem.Name;
                            
                            foreach (var child in clipSwapItem.TreeChildren)
                            {
                                if (child.IsTree)
                                {
                                    MakeTree(child, foldout);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ObjectField item = FluentUIElements.NewObjectField(child.Name, typeof(AnimationClip), child.Clip)
                                        .ChildOf(foldout);
                            
                                    item.RegisterValueChangedCallback(x =>
                                    {
                                        child.Clip = x.newValue as AnimationClip;
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        MakeTree(clip, clipsContainer);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ObjectField item = FluentUIElements.NewObjectField(clip.Name, typeof(AnimationClip), clip.Clip)
                            .ChildOf(clipsContainer);
                            
                        item.RegisterValueChangedCallback(x =>
                        {
                            clip.Clip = x.newValue as AnimationClip;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var operationsArea = new VisualElement()
            .WithClass("top-spaced")
            .WithFlexDirection(FlexDirection.Row)
            .ChildOf(this);
        var mergeOnCurrent = FluentUIElements
            .NewButton("Apply on current", "Apply the changes on this controller")
            .WithClass("grow-control")
            .ChildOf(operationsArea);
        var mergeOnNew = FluentUIElements
            .NewButton("Apply on new", "Apply the changes on a new copy of the controller and applies it to the avatar")
            .WithClass("grow-control")
            .ChildOf(operationsArea);
        var cancelButton = FluentUIElements
            .NewButton("Cancel", "Cancel operation")
            .WithClass("grow-control")
            .ChildOf(operationsArea);

        cancelButton.clicked += () => OnClose?.Invoke();

        mergeOnCurrent.clicked += () =>
        {
            layer.SetController(layer.Controller.SwapAnimations(_animationsToSwap));
            OnClose?.Invoke();
        };
        
        mergeOnNew.clicked += () =>
        {
            layer.SetController(layer.Controller.SwapAnimations(_animationsToSwap, true));
            OnClose?.Invoke();
        };

    }
}
```

}

Comment: This area specified requesting a return method.             public class ClipSwapAreaElement : VisualElement
    {
        public Action OnClose { get; set; }

        private List<ClipSwapAreaElement> _animationsToSwap;